# Заменить индексы на значение из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток господа. имеется следующее
`foreach ($result_list as $entry2) {
  $row[$entry2["id"]][] = $entry2["value_obj"];
}`

выводит он так

```
Array
(
    [324] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 21
            [3] => 26
            [4] => 44
            [5] => 33
            [6] => 88
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 1
        )

    [307] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 48
            [2] => 67
            [3] => 88
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 52
            [7] => 55
            [8] => 56
            [9] => 58
        )
```

Где 324 и 307 ид товара а все что в массиве его характеристики. Вопрос как сделать так что бы вместо индексов отображались названия характеристик которые я беру из БД "param_name"

```
$result=mysql_query($sql );

$result_list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $result_list[] = $row;
}
```

Вот запрос но дело в том что когда я делаю так     `$row[$entry2["id"]][]=$entry2["param_name"]. $entry2["value_obj"];` то он мне все выводит только через запятую

```
$sql="SELECT ore_apartment_city.name_ru,address_ru,description_ru,lat,lng,ore_apartment.id,phone,ore_apartment_obj_type.name_ru,ore_apartment_kind.representation,price,ore_apartment_properties.property_id,ore_apartment_properties.value_obj,ore_additional_properties.name,ore_additional_properties.param_name
FROM ore_apartment,ore_apartment_city,ore_apartment_obj_type,ore_apartment_kind,ore_apartment_properties,ore_additional_properties
WHERE ore_apartment_city.id=ore_apartment.city_id AND ore_apartment_obj_type.id=ore_apartment.obj_type_id AND ore_apartment_kind.id=ore_apartment.kind_id AND ore_apartment.id = ore_apartment_properties.apartment_id  AND ore_additional_properties.id = ore_apartment_properties.property_id";
```

Comment: Необходим код, который поясняет что такое $result_list

Comment: Пардоньте 
`
$result=mysql_query($sql );

$result_list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  
  $result_list[] = $row;
}`

Comment: PHP отображает то, что получил от сервера MySQL. И полученная информация как бы намекает, что нужной тебе информации в этих данных тупо нет. Что означает одно - ты не то просил от сервера. Так что не надо пытаться извлечь из отданного тебе набора данных то, чего в нём нет, и спросить. иначе. То есть изменить запрос к MySQL-серверу. Но вот текста запроса я в твоём вопросе как-то не вижу.

Comment: @Akina Добавил к посту, ибо было превышение знаков

Comment: Что-то текст запроса несильно соответствует полученному результату... в запросе выбирается 14 полей, а в результате его выполнения с полями негусто. Ну и неплохо бы рассказать, где лежат столь необходимые _названия характеристик_, и что это за БАЗА ДАННЫХ "param_name". PS. задайте всем таблицам в тексте запроса алиасы - текст сильно сократится. И укажите для ВСЕХ полей алиасы таблиц, это снимет неоднозначность.

Comment: @Akina Видимо я не понял ваш тролинг, если что пардоньте что сумбурно так все описываю(первый раз как никак). Все хранится в базе от CMS OpenRealEstate Из этой базы я выдергиваю обьявления, и характеристики все хочу закинуть в массив и записать в xml. половину уже сделал но теперь что бы мне легче было разобраться и что бы не было ошибок хочу что бы вместо индексов в массиве были значения из поля param_name

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, что есть "param_name" - база данных или поле. Или, может, таблица?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал

```
foreach ($result_list as $entry2) {
  $row[$entry2["id"]][$entry2["param_name"]]=$entry2["value_obj"];
}
```

А многоуважемому @Akina желаю оставить свой сверх разум при себе и не давать "очень нужные" советы и отводить дальше от темы человека который в этом еще плохо разбирается

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял, что вы хотите, то, как-то так:

```
foreach ($result_list as $entry2) {
    $row[$entry2["id"]] = [$entry2["param_name"] => $entry2["value_obj"]];
}
```

Comment: в точку проверю отпишу

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Comment: а, у вас пых старый - не поддерживает короткую запись массива - []

Comment: $row[$entry2["id"]] = array($entry2["param_name"] => $entry2["value_obj"]); - так должно сработать ^_^